# Should I store UTC timestamps or localtime for shifts

Tags: database, postgresql, timezone, time-and-attendance

I am working on a function that will work out how many workers is on duty and clocked in (or not clocked in) for their shift.

The workers "clock in" and "out" and the time stamps of these events will be stored in UTC format since that seems to be the recommendation that comes up the most.

But the shifts start at fixed local time, so for example one shift will always start at 07:00, regardless of daylight savings, and end at for example 14:00.

The shift workers are "allocated" to shifts.

The first requirement is to be able to know how many of the workers are on duty (clocked in) for their shift "at this point in time" - A kind of status check.

The second requirement is to be able to get a report of a day in the past for example for an individual worker (was the worker on duty for the whole shift, was he late, did they leave late and require overtime to be paid, etc)

So not assuming that everything will always be in only one timezone, the idea is to store the timezone in the database along with the definition of the shifts (The shift record may contain a local start time, end time, and the local time zone "name".)

Question 1: What format is recommended for storing the local timezone? Is there a way in which I can store the start/end times of shifts that allows me to write an SQL query that can compare those times with a supplied UTC time.

Question 2: Is there another suggestion?  Should I just store the clock in/out times as Local to be the same as the shift start/end times?  Or should I do some magic and store everything as UTC times ... But how to work out the current Local time start time of a shift if it is stored as "2:00 UTC" .... converting that to Local Time needs to always be the same, eg 7:00 local time, regardless of DST....

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, understand that date-time is barely touched on by the [SQL standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Interoperability_and_standardization). Data types, definitions, and behavior vary *widely* across various database products.

Fortunately for you, [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) has exceptionally rich handling of [date-time data types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) and [date-time functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html). But you must study the documentation carefully and experiment so you understand behavior.

> 07:00, regardless of daylight savings

Actually, that would not be *regardless* but *respecting* [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). DST is changing the meaning of 7 AM by sliding it later or earlier by an hour. **Respecting DST correctly is the heart of your problem.**

For the sake of other readers, a word about terminology: The “localtime” word in the context of the Question means a date and/or a time-of-day without regard for time zone or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

As such, a local-date-time does *not* represent a point on the timeline but rather a rough idea of *possible* points. In Auckland NZ, 7 AM arrives much earlier than in Paris FR. And in turn, 7 AM in Paris FR happens much sooner than 7 AM in Montréal CA. So without a time zone, a “local” value has no meaning. In Postgres, these “local” types are:

- `timestamp without time zone` (date & time-of-day)
- `date`  (date only)
- `time without time zone`  (time-of-day only)

An actual moment on the timeline requires a zone or offset. Let’s call these “zoned” types, for lack of a better word. In Postgres that would be:

- `timestamp with time zone` (date & time-of-day, adjusted to [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time))
- `time with time zone` (time-of-day, adjusted to UTC)

Very important to understand that Postgres *never* saves any time zone information. Despite the “with time zone” name, the zone is not saved as part of your data. Instead, “with time zone” means “*with respect for* time zone” in that Postgres adjusts the input value to [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

- For the zoned types, Postgres applies any specified zone/offset info in the input value to **adjust from that zone/offset to UTC**. The specified zone/offset info is then discarded.
- In contrast, for the “local” types, any specified **zone/offset info is ignored entirely**.

> Question 1: What format is recommended for storing the local timezone?

So, depending on your business needs and rules, you may want to separately record the zone/offset separately, in addition to the date-time value. Neither Postgres nor the SQL standard specify a data type for zone or offset. So I suggest storing as text.

- **Offset-from-UTC**

  - Use the formats specified by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for [designators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators). These formats are primarily (a) `Z` for UTC (short for Zulu, means UTC) and (b) `±hh:mm` where `+` means ahead of UTC (like India) and `-` (the [MINUS character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minus_sign), or alternatively a [HYPHEN-MINUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus)) means behind UTC (like the Americas).
  - While omitting the padded zero on the hour, and omitting the colon, are allowed by ISO 8601, I suggest you never do so. Many protocols and software implementations expect those bits and may break without them.
  - Example: For India, five and a half hours ahead of UTC, `+05:30`
- **Time zone**

  - Use the formal name in format of `continent/region` defined by the IANA in the `tzdata` database, formerly known as the Olson database. See [this recent list of zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).
  - Example: For India, `Asia/Kolkata`

More terminology: An offset-from-UTC is a number of hours and minutes and seconds ahead of, or behind, UTC. A time zone is an offset *plus* a set of rules for handling anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). So always better to use a time zone when you know it.

To answer the Question:
**You need both “local” and “zoned” types for your solution.**

To record the definition of a shift, you want a “local” time-of-day, the `time without time zone`. When you record that shift should normally start at 7 AM, you do not want Postgres to alter or adjust that value.

To record the *concept* of a particular shift, you would record (a) the start time as `time without time zone`, (b) the date as `date`. By applying an offset or zone, you can determine a UTC value. You may want to also/instead record the UTC value itself. But beware of doing so far into the future, as politicians everywhere are quite fond of redefining time zones with little advance notice.

To record the moment a work actually clocked-in, you want the UTC moment, the `timestamp with time zone` type. You can input a zoned value if need be, and Postgres will adjust into UTC. As mentioned in the Question, when working with actual moments on the timeline, it is almost always best to work and store data in UTC.

For both both of the types, you may or may not wish to additionally record the intended time zone as well.

A Postgres session has a default time zone. I suggest you never rely on that. Better to always specify the intended time zone in your SQL code and/or your input data. When manually perusing data, you may find it handy to set the session default to UTC or to a zone, but I would not do that in code.

> Is there a way in which I can store the start/end times of shifts that allows me to write an SQL query that can compare those times with a supplied UTC time.

As mentioned above, you would record the general concept of a shift as a “local”. As in, “In 2015 the Dusseldorf and Detroit factories started at 6 AM while the Delhi factor started at 7 AM, but in 2016 all three factories start at 7 AM”. To record any one actual shift, record in UTC though you may *also* want to record the “local” values for readability by humans.

> Should I just store the clock in/out times as Local to be the same as the shift start/end times?

No, no, certainly not. Any actual points on the time line, real moments, should be recorded in UTC. Use `timestamp with time zone` and let Postgres adjust inputs to UTC as needed. Though generally I suggest your app’s programming be in UTC beforehand.

> Or should I do some magic and store everything as UTC times

No magic needed, just consistent handling of your data to always include time zone (or offset) data and adjust into UTC. Get this straight in your app programming as well as the database. For example, in [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)), hand off objects rather than mere strings for date-time values. With [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) 4.2 the database can exchange [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) (and, optionally, [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) or [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)) objects. (Avoid the troublesome [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html) & [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html) classes, now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system).)

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

> how to work out the current Local time start time of a shift if it is stored as "2:00 UTC"

If you have a date and a time-of-day in UTC, you can always apply a time zone (or offset) to see the “local” value.

Date-time handling is tricky slippery stuff. So think it through, give yourself time to learn, and practice, practice, practice. Tips: (a) Learn 24-hour time, (b) When at work programming, **think in UTC**, keep a UTC clock on your desk, and forget about your own personal local time zone. Thinking primarily in your own local time zone, and constantly translating back-and-forth with UTC, will drive you crazy and lead to errors.